# sqlalchemy - pass through exact pyodbc string returning SQL server permission error?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

The following code is working only using pyodbc -

```
conn_string = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
sql_query = 'SELECT * FROM table'
df = pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn)
```

However, when I try to use the [pass through exact pyodbc string](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#hostname-connections) method of creating a sqlaclehmy engine, I get a permission error -

```
conn_string = 'DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_string)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
engine.connect()
```

Error -

```
SAWarning: Could not fetch transaction isolation level, tried views: ('sys.dm_exec_sessions', 
'sys.dm_pdw_nodes_exec_sessions'); final error was: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft]
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]User does not have permission to perform this action. 
(6004) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

(I tried with and without the port included)

I'm confused on where this permission error is coming from because its working when only using pyodbc. is there some parameter im missing here?

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with sqlaclehmy and SQL DW. According to [this issue](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/issues/105), a workaround is to grant the user `GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE`.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Solution - https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/issues/105

> I know this is an older issue, but since I just resolved a similar
> issue, I'd thought I would share. This is an issue with SQL DW, not
> the SQL Alchemy engine that ipython-sql uses.
>
> I did notice that configuring SQL Magic to use autocommit doesn't seem
> to work with MSSQL. Go ahead and add that to your connection string:
>
> %sql mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@MSSQL_DSN?autocommit=true
>
> You should be able to connect using an Admin account. For general
> users:
>
> "Could not fetch transaction isolation level" is a SQL error. This
> means the user does not have permissions to see what the current
> isolation is. For Azure SQL Data Warehouse, those permissions are in
> this view:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-pdw-exec-connections-transact-sql
>
> Since VIEW SERVER STATE is not supported in SQL DW, you need to use
> "GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO user" instead:
> https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43a4f051-2a12-4a15-8362-3d7a67f5c88f/unable-to-give-permission-on-azure-sql-data-warehouse-catalog-views-and-dmvs?forum=AzureSQLDataWarehouse